# Download video+audio in a single file from YouTube

Tags: windows, cmd, download, youtube, youtube-dl

I tryed to download a video+audio from YouTube by using youtube-dl:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wfUUZvybPY
```

I got a video file (.webm) without audio. I'm looking for a way to download video+audio in a single file by using the command line (cmd) in Windows 10. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
youtube-dl.exe --format mp4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wfUUZvybPY
```

However, youtube-dl relies on ffmpeg for many format conversions. Install ffmpeg for Windows and look at [youtube-dl docs here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#on-windows-how-should-i-set-up-ffmpeg-and-youtube-dl-where-should-i-put-the-exe-files)

Comment: Hello @pierpy thank you very much for your answer. Do you know how to download the above video at the maximum audio and video quality available on YouTube?

Comment: Hello, ciao Gennaro, every video on YouTube has dozen of formats, so there is not a "maximum" absolute quality on their site. `youtube-dl` tries **always** best download options for each url given. It's possible, too, download separate streams ( best audio and best video) and merge them with `ffmpeg`, but that's another story :-)

Comment: Thank you @pierpy; take a look to this question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66867315/best-audio-and-video-quality-not-working-in-youtube-dl

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution; the following command merges the audio and video files in a file.mkv:

```
youtube-dl.exe --sub-lang en --write-sub https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wfUUZvybPY
```