# Best audio and video quality not working in youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

I tried the following command in order to get the best video and audio quality (I can also avoid to write --format best because from the documentation I read that this is the default setting):

```
youtube-dl.exe --format best https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wfUUZvybPY
```

and I got a video.mp4 with the following characteristics:

[image]

I downloaded the same video by using 4k Video Downloader and I got:

[image]

How can I get the same result also by using youtube-dl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse all formats available with:
`youtube-dl.exe -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wfUUZvybPY`
Look at first column, "format code". For this video, best option is:
`youtube-dl --format 315 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wfUUZvybPY` for  3440x1440 video, and
`youtube-dl --format 140 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wfUUZvybPY` for 129kbit audio.
Then, with `ffmpeg`, you can merge that two streams in your preferred container (you can find many answers here in Stackoverflow).
For very high bitrates there isn't a file already merged available on YouTube, `ffmpeg` is a crucial tool for this type of conversions!

Comment: if I want the format obtained by using 4k video downloade, do I need to split audio and video or is it possible to download a single file?

Comment: As said, if you don't want follow `youtube-dl` automatick picks, you must select manually whatever format is best for you :-) 
In this case, looks like 4k video downloads has picked is `299`, or `303`
But there is no way to "repeat" this best pick, maybe that  on other videos `youtube.dl` picks best format, and 4K worse :-)

Answer (score 1):

use

> yt-dlp

insted . its a new fork of youtube-dl with new features and fixes and you should use this option >>

```
yt-dlp --merge-output-format webm http://youtube-url
```

this will download the best audio and video quality and fixes no audio issue